# UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceive is not getting triggered in iOS with Flutter App

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apple-push-notifications, aws-pinpoint

I have setup push notifications using APNS for iOS (Using Swift) in the flutter App. didReceiveRemoteNotification is getting triggered when the app receives a push notification from AWS Pinpoint. But none of the other methods are getting triggered when the user taps the notification. Once I handle the user action on the push notification, I can call a scheme using openUrl to specific route on the app.

I have tried by disabling/enabling background modes in the capabilities in the Xcode. Also verified that push notifications are turned on in the capabilities. Pinpoint uses APNS to send the notification to iOS and Firebase to send the notification to Android which is working fine.

Also tried with iOS target version as 10.0, 11.0 and 12.0

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self 
is declared in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and imported UserNotifications

When I tap the push notification, this is getting printed in the console:

Warning: UNUserNotificationCenter delegate received call to -userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

Payload from pinpoint:

```
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "BODY";
        title = "TITLE";
    };
    badge = 0;
    "content-available" = 1;
    "mutable-content" = 0;
    sound = default;
}]
```

Code,

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

            let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

            // Print full message.
            print(userInfo)

            // Change this to your preferred presentation option
            completionHandler([])
        }

        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

            // Print full message.
            print(userInfo)

            completionHandler()
        }

    }
```

didReceive is expected to get triggered when the user taps on the push notification which is not happening in my case.

Can anyone help me on how to trigger when the user taps the push notification?

Comment: Try to set "mutable-content" as "1".

Comment: That didn't work. I guess that is mainly used to modify the notification content as per the docs here. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html

Comment: The one I tried yesterday is "The same code is working for Native iOS App with Swift"
When the same code is running through flutter app, it is not working. The major difference is the FlutterAppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. iOS swift delegate methods were not triggered. It appears that the methods must have been declared public.

Just replace

```
func userNotificationCenter
```

with

```
public func userNotificationCenter
```

Maybe it will helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set center's delegate property?

```
center.delegate = self
```

where `self` is `AppDelegate`.